# Number systems and Cardinality Question (to admit a bijection)

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, number-systems

I am trying to complete the following proof:

Show that the real numbers are unique, in the sense that any complete
ordered field admits a bijection with R that preserves addition, multiplication, and order.

what does it mean for a filed to admit a bijection?

Comment: I would say just that there EXISTS a bijection from that field to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about proving that a bijection preserves addition, multiplication and order? I am assuming it would rely on the fact that we have a complete ordered field in the first place and that somehow addition and multiplication behaves the same way after applying the bijective function.